# How to use MsBuild.exe to build a fortran/c mixed project?

Tags: msbuild, fortran, intel-fortran

## 1. Background

I have a project which is managed by `cmake`, I then generate the solution files by Visual Studio 2019 geneartor. The folder strucutre looks like:

```
- main.sln
  - fotran_proj.vfproj (output a static lib libfortran.lib)
  - C_proj.vcxproj (dependent on libfortran.lib)
  - ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

It contains both `fortran` and `c` projects, and `c` project is dependent on `fortran` project.

**I want to build the whole solution from commandline by `msbuild.exe`**.

## 2. Environment

I use `VS2019` with `Intel Fortran Compiler` on win10.

## 3. Question

When I try to use `msbuild.exe` to build it:

```
MSBuild.exe /t:build ALL_BUILD
```

It simply build the `vcxproj` part and ignore the `vfproj` parts. Why? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't do this. Intel Fortran's build system isn't recognized by `msbuild`, though that integration might happen sometime in the future.

What you can do is use `devenv` from the command line to build your mixed-language solution. From an Intel Fortran command prompt window (or one where you have established the Intel environment), type `devenv /?` to see the usage and options. For example, I built a mixed-language solution as follows:

`devenv C_calls_F.sln /build "Debug|Win32"`

Comment: Thanks sir, you are correct. This method works. If Visual Studio can support this governing feature, we just don't need to work so hard.